# js discord bot audio player

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

It logs in and doesn't show any errors but doesn't produce music
when a year enters a discord channel. It’s as if he’s playing music, but you can’t hear it. His microphone is open.

```
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});

const player = createAudioPlayer({
    behaviors: {
        noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.Pause,
    },
});

const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtU7SwM-GTc"

const resource = createAudioResource(ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly' }));

player.play(resource);
connection.subscribe(player);
```